# Module '"@testing-library/react"' has no exported member 'waitFor'

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library, testing-library

Since today, I started to get this type error and bunch of others regarding "@testing-library/react"

I followed a similar [GitHub issue](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/610) and they are seem to be relevant but not an answer of why this might happen!

Things that I'm getting this error on are:

- fireEvent
- screen
- waitFor
- waitForElementToBeRemoved

I Also tried using [this page](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/intro) it helped a bit but still i really have no idea where to get waitFor, waitForElementToBeRemoved and others that might needed. they are coming from `@testing-library/react` but why typescript gives me that error I absolutely have no idea!

I'm using pnpm and my pkg versions are latest ones:

```json
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.0.0",
"@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: what's your react version?

Comment: "react": "^18.2.0"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after investigating this issue a lot, I figured out a solution from some other projects of mine which was exactly using the same pkgs but they did not have any error.

So I clicked on the type definition of `waitFor` in there and started to chase that within node_modules directory of that project.

after a while, i did notice that `waitFor` comes from `@testing-library/dom` and i wondered if i have that package installed or not!

soon after I installed that package, it fixed my issue **BUT** I wonder what this pkg `@testing-library/jest-dom` doing then?

Comment: Thank you. Installing `@testing-library/dom` and also actually upgrading `@testing-library/jest-dom` from v5.16.5 to v6.1.3. solved my issue. BTW, what package manager do you use? Didn't you by any chance transition to PNPM recently? Because I have a feeling these errors started to occur at the same time.

Comment: yes, I'm using pnpm. I kinda get a feeling that pnpm does not install dependencies of dependency and later, I saw it that they mentioned it in their docs